# How to save data to the database when the user registers, ie how to remember the data with which he registered in the database? (Give error)

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

> User.cs:
> The following error occurs in this class: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression > State
> Error CS0119 'User' is a type, which is not valid in the given context TestBlazor C: \ ...
> There I tried to save the data when the user registers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestBlazor.Models;

namespace TestBlazor.Data
{
    public class Users
    {
        public static void AddUsers()
        {
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                //var user = new User { Url = "" }; //what this?
                context.User.Add(User); //this error
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Here I linked the Model to the database. I get the table (Users) empty.
> AppDbContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestBlazor.Models;

namespace TestBlazor.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext()
        {

        }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=testblazor;Integrated Security=True;");
            }
        }

        //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        //{
        //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        //}

        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }


    }

}
```

> Here is the Model (User):
> User.cs

```
 [Table("Users")]
    public class User
    {
        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName is required.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "password must be atleast 8 characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company is required.")]
        [Remote("doesCompanyExist", "Company", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Company already exists. Please enter a different company.")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        public User GetRegisteredUser()
        {
            return new User
            {
                UserName = UserName,
                Password = Password,
                Email = Email,
                Company = Company,

            };
        }

    }
```

> Here is the registration layout:
> Register.razor:

```
@page "/register"

@using TestBlazor.Models

<br />
<br />

<h3><b>Register</b></h3>
<br />

<EditForm class="needs-validation" Model="@_user" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
    <div class="alert @StatusClass">@StatusMessage</div>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>User name</b></p>
        <input id="username" class="solid" name="username" placeholder="Your username.." @bind-value="_user.UserName" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.UserName)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Password</b></p>
        <input type="password" class="solid" id="password" placeholder="Your password.." @bind-value="_user.Password" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Password)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Email</b></p>
        <input id="email" class="solid" placeholder="you@example.com" @bind-value="_user.Email" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Email)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><b>Company</b></p>
        <input id="company" class="solid" placeholder="Your company.." @bind-value="_user.Company" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Company)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>


    <br />

    <button disabled="@loading" class="btn btn-primary">

        @if (loading)
        {
            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
            <NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Register</NavLink>
        }
        Register
    </button>
    <NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Login</NavLink>
</EditForm>



@code {
    private User _user = new User();

    private string StatusMessage;
    private string StatusClass;

    private bool loading;


    private void OnValidSubmit()
    {
        if (loading == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have successfully registered!");
        }

        else
        {
            loading = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Check your information again!");
        }
    }

    protected void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        StatusClass = "alert-info";
        StatusMessage = " You have successfully registered! Please click the Login button to log in!";
    }

    protected void HandleInvalidSubmit()
    {
        StatusClass = "alert-danger";
        StatusMessage = " Check your information again!";
    }


    public bool doesCompanyExist(string Company)
    {
        try
        {

            if (Company != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are trying to add `User`, which is a class, to the User table via entity framework. You should uncomment this line `//var user = new User { Url = "" }; //what this?` and modify this line `context.User.Add(User);` by passing `user` into it instead. So, it might look like this.

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var user = new User { Url = "" };
    context.User.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I didn't even look at all of your other code.

edit: I don't see `Url` as being a property of `User` so I am not sure why you are trying to initialize a new `User` with `Url`. But assuming you initialize an instance of `User` properly (I am referring to the line of code `var user = new User { ... };` you should be able to use the `.Add()` method to add it to the `User` table via EF.